# File_get_contents with PHP to retrieve JSON output of code as opposed to source code when file is on same server

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

I have a server file with a .php extension that retrieves data from a database and outputs it as JSON. I am trying to get this output from a separate file in the same directory, however, when I use file_get_contents, instead of retrieving the output, it is retrieving the source code. When applied to an external URL, file_get_contents obviously can't get the source of the files on the server but only the output (albeit the source code of the output).

The file outputs its content with:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode(array('item'=>$dataobject));
```

I am trying to get the output with:

```
$object = file_get_contents("myfile.php");
```

What is the property way to retrieve the output of a file, as opposed to source code when the file is in the same directory?

Comment: Do you mean using something like `require`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **direct** route would be to use a URL instead of a file path so that the data is fetched over HTTP and the web server generates the response to the URL by executing the PHP program.

The **better** approach would be to refactor the code into a function, include the file, then call the function.

### mylib.php

```
function getJSON() {
    return json_encode(array('item'=>$dataobject));
}
```

### myfile.php

```
include("mylib.php");
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo getJSON();
```

### other.php

```
include("mylib.php");
$object = getJSON();
```

Comment: @user6631314 — No. I mean mylib.php … which I provided under a *huge* heading of **mylib.php** in my example code.

Comment: Ok. I'll try it out.I guess I'm being dense, but I don't see how mylib.php knows what $dataobject is if it is not an argument to the function

Comment: On the first option, of just calling the server, through https it seems that the session variables are not shared which is how I'm doing authentication? Is that possible?

Comment: Since the request is coming from your server and not from the user's browser you won't get the user's cookies which are how sessions are tracked.

Comment: "but I don't see how mylib.php knows what $dataobject is if it is not an argument to the function" — It wasn't defined in the code in your question either. So however your code does it.

Comment: $dataobject is pulled from dbase by myfile which does most of the work I need to get that object into other.php.  I can include $dataobject as argument of mylib function so you have getJSON($dataobject) {
    return json_encode(array('item'=>$dataobject));
} however I think I still need a way to get the dataobject into other.php. What do you think of using ob_start to buffer output?

Comment: Move the logic into the library

Comment: I got it to work by moving everything into the function. So I ended up with two files, the calling file and the file with the function. Not exactly what I wanted but worked

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand, why you want do that. That is not a good approach. But anyway, this might be helpful.

File 1 -  test1.php

```
<?php
echo json_encode(['year'=>2020]);
?>
```

File 2 - test2.php

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("http://localhost/test1.php");
?>
```

Remove localhost with your url.